# Connecting a Virtual Network on a Dell's ESXi with a network in VMware Workstation without Bridging

Tags: networking, vmware-workstation, bridged, host-only

I have a Dell Server (192.168.10.10) connected to Windows laptop (192.168.10.5) via regular Ethernet LAN. The Dell Server is running ESXi (192.168.10.15) server on it. A Firewall VM (firewallsm, 192.168.10.7) is running on the ESXi that has network 10.0.64.0 / 27 behind it.

On the Windows laptop I have VMware Workstation installed, A Firewall VM (firewallwm, 192.168.10.3) is running on it with the network 192.168.28.0 / 27 behind it.

I wanted to connect the network running on ESXi (10.0.64.0) to VMware Workstation's Host-Only network on my laptop. I tried many things like `route add 192.168.10.0 mask 255.255.255.0 192.168.99.0`, ICS (Internet Connection Sharing), putting the VMware Workstation's Host-Only network in 192.168.10.0, adding a Bridged NIC in VMware Workstation, none of these worked, the Dell Server would just not ping the Host-Only (192.168.10.2) interface of VMware Workstation even though both (dell and VMware Workstation Host-Only) were in the same network.

I eventually Bridged the windows Ethernet LAN (Connected to Dell) to Host-Only NIC of VMware Workstation (192.168.10.1), and finally got it working but every now and then the Bridge causes BSoD with Bridge.sys file.

I need to know how can get the 2 networks connected without a Bridge, any router software I can use, or any other way.

[Network Diagram](https://i.ibb.co/wwPLH2H/Network.png)

Comment: Host only Mode is an isolated guest. The Server ESX should already be using Bridged Network Mode. Put your other machine Workstation Guest machine on its Bridged network and see if you can connect that way.

Comment: VMware Workstation can have a VM with Bridged NIC but ESXi does not have any kind of Bridged network, unless I'm misunderstanding something

Comment: The last time I worked on ESX (some time back)  the ESX network mode was bridged. If I am mistaken then NAT on the Server will work with Bridged on the host.

Comment: Where can I find those settings, to my knowledge I was unable to set bridged mode in ESXi, are you talking about Promiscuous Mode ?!

Comment: No not promiscuous- just NAT. It has been a while so I will see if I can find settings for you.

Comment: Here is a Settings VMware tutorial. ESXI is just Bridged networking;  It does not have NAT mode.   https://communities.vmware.com/t5/ESXi-Discussions/Bridge-NAT-networking-option-missing-in-ESXi-6/td-p/1807612

Comment: OK, then I'l keep the firewallwm NIC in Bridged mode and see

Comment: I'm afraid that didn't work, I had set the firewall VM in Workstation as Bridged (192.168.1.4), Windows NIC connected to Dell (192.168.1.20), Dell (192.168.1.19), Windows Laptop NIC (192.168.1.17). The ESXi could not ping the Windows Laptop NIC and thus ESXi could not ping any further, firewall Bridged NIC (192.168.1.4)

Comment: Everything is on subnet  .1  .  I will keep looking around.

Comment: Thats correct, I put all on subnet .1 to see if they'd ping, windows laptop can ping esxi but not the other way around.

Comment: Check on your workstation machines (real and guest) that Network Discovery is ON. That is not default.

Comment: Thanks @John the Bridging was the solution, in VMware Virtual Network Editor the Bridging was set to Automatic, it was changed to the Windows NIC interface (connected to dell), and this made it work properly. Not sure how to put your response as an Answer ?!

Comment: If I make an answer of my main thoughts would you find that helpful?

Comment: Yes as it was beneficial all the way I just hadn't mentioned or asked more about it..

Comment: I have posted an answer for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this setup, Host only Mode is an isolated guest and Host Only prevents outside connections. You will need to use NAT or Bridged Network mode and I suggest using Bridged Mode.

The Server ESX should already be using Bridged Network Mode. Put your other machine Workstation Guest machine on its Bridged network and see if you can connect that way.

Here is a Settings VMware tutorial. ESXI is just Bridged networking; It does not have NAT mode.

> Edit ESXi vSwitch0 configuration and change the promiscuous mode
> inside the "security" tab from reject to accept, now the hosts who live inside the VM will be able to bridge the main VM adapter

Use Bridged Mode on the Workstation Guest mahcine. Keep everything on one subnet. Check on your workstation machines (real and guest) that Network Discovery is ON.

[ESX Settings Mode](https://communities.vmware.com/t5/ESXi-Discussions/Bridge-NAT-networking-option-missing-in-ESXi-6/td-p/1807612)